# install mpfr: get into multiple errors

Tags: installation, mpfr, texinfo

I want to install **mpfr** package as a non root user.  I built it using this:

```
./configure --with-gmp-lib=/data/home/parisa/gmp-6.1.2/lib
```

, but after **make** I got the following error

```
WARNING: 'makeinfo' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified a '.texi' file, or
         any other file indirectly affecting the aspect of the manual.
         You might want to install the Texinfo package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/>
         The spurious makeinfo call might also be the consequence of
         using a buggy 'make' (AIX, DU, IRIX), in which case you might
         want to install GNU make:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/make/>
make[1]: *** [mpfr.info] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory `/data/home/parisa/mpfr-3.1.5/doc'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I searched this error in Internet, but I couldn't find something useful and easy to understand. So, I tried to install **texinfo**, but after **configuring** this warning message appears:

```
WARNING: 'aclocal-1.15' is missing on your system.
         You should only need it if you modified 'acinclude.m4' or
         'configure.ac' or m4 files included by 'configure.ac'.
         The 'aclocal' program is part of the GNU Automake package:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/automake>
         It also requires GNU Autoconf, GNU m4 and Perl in order to run:
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf>
         <http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/>
         <http://www.perl.org/>
make: *** [aclocal.m4] Error 127
```

I also tried `autoreconf -f -i` before configuring, but with no success. I tried to use **automake** installed on our cluster by using LD_LIBRARY_PATH but again nothing changed.

Comment: texinfo needs `tgetent` function from `/usr/lib/libcurses.a` (actually, it is symlink to `/usr/ccs/lib/libxcurses.a`, coming from package: `bos.rte.libcur`)

Comment: I just installed ncurse package, and I added `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/home/parisa/ncurse/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LIBRARY_PATH=/data/home/parisa/ncurse/lib:$LIBRARY_PATH
export CPATH=/data/home/parisa/ncurse/include:$CPATH` to the .bashrc , but the warning still exists, have I edited **.bashrc** correctly?

Comment: Exactly why did you install `ncurse`? You should have the library I have mentioned earlier. Also please read this: http://web.axelero.hu/lzsiga/aix-linking.html#Q0007

Comment: You are right, I used those installed on the clustere and that warning disappeared, and I edited the question.

Comment: You can download automake from here: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/